GridView inside a container in Flutter for web
Im trying to implement a gridview inside a row for flutter web,I did it fix on the screen, but It do not scroll inside the container, I got bottom overflow-error. Can anybody help me?

...
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  FilledButton(
                      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: !isAudioView
                              ? const Color(0xffebeffa)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                          fixedSize: const Size(114, 43)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isAudioView = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Videos",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: !isAudioView
                                ? const Color(0xff0038B8)
                                : const Color(0xff7f9bdb)),
                      )),
                  FilledButton(
                      style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                          backgroundColor: isAudioView
                              ? const Color(0xffebeffa)
                              : Colors.transparent,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                          fixedSize: const Size(114, 43)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isAudioView = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Músicas",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: isAudioView
                                ? const Color(0xff0038B8)
                                : const Color(0xff7f9bdb)),
                      ))
                ],
              ).withPadding(
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 62, top: 47, right: 24)),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 691,
                child: VerticalDivider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  indent: 0,
                  endIndent: 0,
                  color: Color(0xff0038B8),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: GridContentView(isAudioView: isAudioView).withPadding(
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top: 47, right: 24),
              ))
            ],
...

}

class GridContentView extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isAudioView;
  const GridContentView({super.key, required this.isAudioView});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 1140,
      child: Expanded(
        child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: isAudioView ? 5 : 3,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
          ),
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried to put singlechildscrollview but it got the last error I found, and so I tried to change the order i put the container, expanded and singlechildscrollview, but no sucsess

Try below code and just remove GridContentView  Expanded from class
child: Expanded( // remove this Expanded because this generates the error -> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget
        child: GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,

I tried Code:
Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              FilledButton(
                style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    fixedSize: const Size(114, 43)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "Videos",
                  style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff7f9bdb)),
                ),
              ),
              FilledButton(
                style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    fixedSize: const Size(114, 43)),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "Músicas",
                  style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff7f9bdb)),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 691,
            child: VerticalDivider(
              thickness: 1,
              indent: 0,
              endIndent: 0,
              color: Color(0xff0038B8),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 1140,
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                ),
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 300,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),

Result- 
